# Can HttpClient's reponse Content be null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

When getting a `HttpResponseMessage` from `HttpClient`, are there any cases where its `Content` may be `null`?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
if (response.Content == null) {
    // Can this happen?
}
else
{
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // ...
}
```

If you think it can be `null`, please provide an example to reproduce it.

I have tried many things, but without being able to get `null`:

```
╔═══════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║        Request        ║            Response             ║        Content        ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ GET  http             ║ 200 OK, a response              ║ The response          ║
║ GET  http             ║ 200 OK, empty response          ║ Empty string          ║
║ GET  http             ║ 204 No Response, empty response ║ Empty string          ║
║ GET  http             ║ 400 Bad Request, a response     ║ The response          ║
║ GET  http             ║ 400 Bad Request, empty response ║ Empty string          ║
║ GET  http             ║ 500 Bad Request, empty response ║ Empty string          ║
║ HEAD http             ║ 200 OK, empty response          ║ Empty string          ║
║ OPTIONS http          ║ 200 OK, empty response          ║ Empty string          ║
║ GET  http, bad DNS    ║ (never hit)                     ║ HttpRequestException  ║
║ GET  http, bad scheme ║ (never hit)                     ║ ArgumentException     ║
║ GET  http             ║ Never respond                   ║ TaskCanceledException ║
╚═══════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: By specification, depending on the response status code, there may be no content in the body. An example is the [`204 No Content` status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204). No idea what C# makes out of this, though.

Comment: `HEAD` also returns no body, yet the Content from HttpClient returns an empty string rather than `null`. It would be interesting to know whether we need to check for `null` or if we can always expect an empty string.

Comment: I've just tried this with a bad scheme and a non-existent host - in those cases the task returned by GetAsync is faulted. I wonder what happens with a server that provides a malformed response...

Comment: You could use an extension method to ensure it is an empty string (i.e. convert `null` to empty string).

Comment: @Namoshek This could be a nice workaround to keep the code clean. But if it is actually unnecessary, I would rather not do it. So, I would like to get to the bottom of this once and for all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added different cases that I've tried to my post, including your two ideas. Still no luck in getting `null` :(

Answer (score 3):

So as [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8), yes it can be null, but you should use `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` to check response valid or not

Comment: This is a very good observation. However, it is still not fully clear since the sentence you are referring to is prefixed with "In .NET Framework and .NET Core 2.2 and earlier versions". Can it still be `null` in .NET Core 3.1? And again, in exactly which situations can it be `null`?